# Send a full formatted mail with google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, sendmail

i am trying to send mails to some list of user using google apps-script.

I am taking the first draft mail and then mailing it to list of users present in the spreadsheet. But when i use ".getplainbody(); " function. It only copies the plain text in the draft.

```
function sendmail() 
{
    var drafts = GmailApp.getDraftMessages();
    Logger.log(drafts.length);
    var draft = drafts[0].getPlainBody();
    Logger.log(draft);

    GmailApp.sendEmail('abc@gmail.com', 'subject', 'Hello' + '\n ' + draft);
}
```

I have also tried using the getbody() and then html with the message.

```
function sendmail() 
{
    var drafts = GmailApp.getDraftMessages();
    Logger.log(drafts.length);
    var draft = drafts[0].getBody();
    Logger.log(draft);

    GmailApp.sendEmail('abc@gmail.com', 'subject', 'Hello' + '\n ' + {html: draft});
}
```

But this also gives me "[object Object]" in the inbox.
Is there any other option to send the draft mail (not in plain text format)with proper format.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `GmailApp.sendEmail('abc@gmail.com', 'subject', 'plaintext body', {htmlBody: draft});`

You are missing the fourth parameter, `'Hello' + '\n ' + {html: draft}` actually concatenates  Hello \n with the {html: draft} object.

Comment: Hi, Now i have a new problem, All photos embedded in mails are delivered as broken to recipient. I can see all photos perfectly in draft and when sending, it is getting delivered as broken image.